# Should we migrate by hand good-but-not-research level questions from MathOverflow?

Tags: discussion, mathoverflow

MathOverflow has a large supply of reasonable to excellent mathematics questions, which have been closed for not being "research level".

> Should we migrate some of these by hand?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea to me, but probably they should be CW since they won't have been asked by the original asker?

Comment: @Noah: But then that would imply the people giving answers will be CW.  I don't think they should be CW.

Comment: Try not to conflate the purpose of community wiki this way. Maybe leave a comment to give the author a chance to ask the question on the new system themselves... after which it is "up for grabs." That's just one possible suggestion.

Comment: But during private beta they *can't* ask the new question themselves.

Comment: @Noah give it a week while we work out some stuff and then they can come flooding in. I'm sure they would love a place that doesn't reject their perfectly good questions for being too easy...

Comment: The facility to vote-to-migrate-automatically is already in place; we do it all the time on SO. So unless there is some technical problem with migrating from SE1 to SE2 sites (only the developers would know that - perhaps you?), I think having a "vote to migrate to math.stackexchange.com" on mathoverflow is a great idea

Answer (score 6):

I don't see anything wrong with asking questions that:

1. You already know the answer to
2. You discovered elsewhere (ie mathoverflow.net)

The goal of the SE model is to be an authoritative reference for people of all levels. I say migrate (by hand of course).

However, when it comes to providing an *answer* from mathoverflow/other site, I think the best practice is to just link to the answer. This way, the original author gets the credit.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a good idea; a similar question was asked for Game Development-related questions at Stack Overflow being moved to the new Game Dev SE Beta.

**Any questions asked at MO and closed can simply be re-asked here**.  There is no need to over-complicate things with possible migration issues.

This is even more complex than the Game Development case, because the Math Overflow database is independently owned apart from Stack Exchange.

Comment: By "migrate by hand" I think Scott means exactly what you're saying we just re-ask the question.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood that as an administrator migrating each question on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 1):

There is no software facility for migrating questions from MO: at present, as Justin says, it is a completely separate system that does not communicate with the Stack Exchange 2 sites.  And of course, right now, the only people who could be reask questions here are those who are invited to the private beta.

It's also unwise for MO to count on this proposal being a place to redirect questions in the future: we're in the second day of private beta, and the site might not make it all the way to live.

Generally, I don't think "migrate" is a good word to use in this context, unless MO does become a Stack Exchange 2 site; people are free to ask questions here, whether they have been closed at MO or not.