# Rendering of some past links to meta seems to be broken after recent changing of url of meta posts

Tags: support, bug, hyperlinks, https

I have noticed this problem, probably connected with recent change of url's of the posts from `meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions` to `https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/`. (This change was also accompanied by some [edits done silently by community bot](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26287/what-to-do-about-these-trivial-edits-http-%E2%86%92-https).)

Non surprisingly many posts on meta contain links to other posts. And, of course, the link was given with the URL which worked at the time. I will include here link to the question with id=1 as an example: 
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-migrate-by-hand-good-but-not-research-level-questions-from-mathoverflo
As you can see, the link is rendered as bare url. If I use the new URL, then it is rendered as a title: [Should we migrate by hand good-but-not-research level questions from MathOverflow?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-migrate-by-hand-good-but-not-research-level-questions-from-mathoverflo)

The problem I see with this is that when any old post including an url was made, the link (with old url) was rendered as a title. (I believe this worked not only for meta, but also for the main site. And perhaps also for other sites I am not entirely sure.) It is not ideal that changes on the meta site also changed how older posts are rendered.

- Is this still in process of being fixed? (Is this only temporary, until community bot finishes editing all links?) If yes, where can I find more about the timeframe when this is supposed to be fixed?
- Why only some of the links to the meta posts in old format has been changed. (It is possible that this is still ongoing, but I am a bit suspicious after seeing that many such silent community user edits have been done on March 16.<sup>1</sup>)
- Are [the remaining links](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Ameta.math.stackexchange.com) starting with `http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/` supposed to be edited manually if we want to render them correctly? (This makes sense at least for posts which are displayed often - just for the comfort of the readers. Leaving a link in some post which is no more relevant is probably not really a big deal. And of course, the links which use `[text](url)` format - see [editing help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#links) - do not cause any problem with rendering.)
- Is this problem for all per-site-metas or is it specific to some sites?

---

<sup>1</sup>Here I am referring specifically to replacing `http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/` with `https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/`.
When I check my [responses tab](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=responses) I see many such edits on March 16. There are some other related actions on other days.
For example, I see changes from `http://math.stackexchange.com/` to `https://math.stackexchange.com/` on April 13, some other SE sites on other dates.

---

Examples:

- You can see in [this question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13619/hot-network-questions-incorrectly-use-mathjax) that a link to another meta post is rendered as a bare url. If you compare the version saved in [Internet Archive in 2015](http://web.archive.org/web/20151023040814/https://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13619/hot-network-questions-incorrectly-use-mathjax) you can see that it was rendered as a title back then.
- [This answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19135/congratulations-the-big-thread/19136#19136) contains list of links to older meta discussions. Again, they are shown as urls, as [Internet Archive version from 2015](http://web.archive.org/web/20151220052859/https://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19135/congratulations-the-big-thread) shows, they used to be rendered as titles. You can also see that in a related answer [the old urls has already been edited](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/16882/revisions) by the Community user and [it is rendered correctly](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16881/are-congratulatory-posts-off-topic-on-meta-or-only-some-of-them/16882#16882).

Comment: Note the SO blog post, [How Stack Overflow Flipped the Switch on HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/22/stack-overflow-flipped-switch-https/), for an indication of the planning behind this change.

Comment: There is a Meta.SE post [Network-wide HTTPS: It's Time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time) being used for progress updates and bug reports.  Note in particular one bug report [from this Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296511/155839) based on using the old `meta.math` syntax rather than the new `math.meta` syntax.  There are some redirects in place intended to bridge this change.

Comment: @hardmath So if I read your comments correctly, I should have posted this as an answer to [Network-wide HTTPS: It's time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058). I'll wait a bit - after all the devs check also per-site-metas for bugs. If nothing happens, I can make a post about this problem there.

Comment: No, I was trying to add a bit of context.  I think it on-topic and worth discussing here for the sake of the immediate "audience".