# Are `math.meta.stackexchange.com` and `meta.math.stackexchange.com` the same website?

Tags: discussion, meta, hyperlinks, url

Are [math.meta.stackexchange.com](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com) and [meta.math.stackexchange.com](https://meta.math.stackexchange.com)  the same website?

The order in which the words "math" and "meta" are swapped.

> - math meta
> - meta math

Comment: I will mention that the old URL only works for me with `http:` - and not with `https:`. Try `https://meta.math.stackexchange.com/` https://meta.math.stackexchange.com/ and `http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/` http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/.
At least one other user confirmed the same behavior [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/64952/2023/3/16).

Answer (score 11):

The network Meta post [Network-wide HTTPS: It's time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058) states:

> ### **Update 2017-03-16**
>
> We've redirected all child meta traffic from `meta.*.stackexchange.com` to `*.meta.stackexchange.com`, and are now forcing HTTPS. We have also rebaked links inside the network (except comments) to point to the new domains and protocol. We'll get to comments at the end.

In particular, all `http://meta.math.stackexchange.com` links now redirect to `https://math.meta.stackexchange.com`. Note that, as indicated in [Martin Sleziak's comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35558/are-math-meta-stackexchange-com-and-meta-math-stackexchange-com-the-same-web/35559#comment167599_35558), using `https:` instead doesn't work properly. Using this with Microsoft Edge results in a "Your connection isn't private" message (and stating it's due to "NET::ERR_CERT_REVOKED"), with Google Chrome showing a "Your connection is not private" message (and indicating it's due to "NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID"), and FireFox giving a "Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead" message.

There's also the related [Rendering of some past links to meta seems to be broken after recent changing of url of meta posts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26454/602049) on this site.

Comment: "child meta traffic", "forcing HTTPS", "rebaked links". They are speaking a different language.

Comment: funny how the comment received more upvotes. It would be helpful for the OP if you add a line stating that the ```meta.math.stackexchange.com``` redirects to ```math.meta.stackexchange.com```

Comment: @DS Thanks for the feedback. Although I'm unsure how helpful adding that line would necessarily be to anybody reading the answer (including for the OP), I agree it's a good idea nonetheless to make this specific redirection more explicit, so I've now made that change.